# How to configure Pygments' HTML formatter in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, pygments

I want to use Jekyll for Github pages and I'm struggling a bit with pygments. Jekyll does not seem to let me configure anything pygments related.

There are two things I want (need) to change:

1. Use *linenos=table* so code can be copied easily. `{% highlight c linenos=table %}` does not work. In addition, it would be more convenient to define this globally and not in every `{% highlight ...`
2. When I use `{% highlight c %}` (notice the **C** lexer) pygments generates something like: `<div class="highlight"><code class="c">...</code></div>`. As a result the class **c** in `<code>` conflicts with the class **c** used for `<span>`s for comments in the highlighted source code. How do I tell pygments to use *classprefix*?

Both are options documented here: http://pygments.org/docs/formatters.

Comment: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#line-numbers linenos doesn't support that. For C you should be able to use the `c` shortname http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-c-c-languages make sure you're using the right stylesheet http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#stylesheets-for-syntax-highlighting